# How to handle multiple touch with Navigation Controller and ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, iostream

I have a Navigation controller in my BaseViewController . I am extending it in each and every controller . I have a graph in my other controller in that i have to save a particular value and that value will be plotted on my graph . The thing is when i click on my save button and back button on my navigation bar at a time  it is saving as well as popping it back to the other view controller and the app is freezing there . Can anyone had this type issue .If so please help me out to get this solution.

Answer (score 1):

May be in your save button, you wrote the Popviewcontroller.check it once your save button code.

Comment: -(void)btnSave_TouchUpInside:(id)sender
{
 isUpdating = YES;
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
 [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
 btnSave.frame = CGRectMake(99, 428, 122, 52);
 [UIView commitAnimations];
 [ssibv.referenceDictionary setObject:strUpdateValue forKey:CDEF_SCROLLER_CURRENT_VALUE_KEY];
 ssibv.strCurrentValue = strUpdateValue;
 
 OptumizeMeAppDelegate * mainDg = (OptumizeMeAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [mainDg startActivityIndicator:@"Loading..." inView:self.view];

Comment: NSThread *tThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(saveOrUpdateTracker) object:nil];
 [tThread start]; 
}